# Spring Boot: how to use Multiple RestTemplates? to make calls with and without SSL certificate verification conditionally

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

We have a spring boot component that calls different 3rd party systems such as

1. Vodafone that requires a SSL handshake
2. and others in which we need to ignore all certificates.

When calling #2 simply without any SSL:

```
 try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        LOG.info("Sending request to url#{}", url);
        LOG.info("URI {}", url);

        HttpGet h = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(h);
```

...

We get the error:

```
 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 | exstart [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) 
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
```

We have tried to instantiate a local RestTemplate that ignores all certificates but it broke the @Autowired RestTemplate bean elsewhere.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

MORE INFO:

Tried Smile's suggestion, still fails for the clients that require SSL

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("RestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


    /**
     * This will return a restTemplate object that will ignore all ssl
     * certificate validation
     *
     * @return
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     */
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("RestTemplateNonSSL")
    public RestTemplate RestTemplateNonSSL() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep two different beans for `RestTemplate` and use `@Qualifier("SOME NAME SIGNIFYING SSL OR NOT")` to differentiate the two beans.

For eg,

```java
@Bean(name="RestTemplateSSL")
public RestTemplate restTemplateSSL(){
    // Create and return SSL specific RestTemplate
}

@Bean(name="RestTemplateNonSSL")
public RestTemplate restTemplateNonSSL(){
    // Create and return Non-SSL specific RestTemplate
}
```

Usage:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("RestTemplateSSL")
private RestTemplate restTemplateSSL;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("RestTemplateNonSSL")
private RestTemplate restTemplateNonSSL;
```

Comment: sounds good but again, it fails the same way. adding more info the question..

Comment: Please update the question with your code where you are autowiring and using the resttemplate objects and also the error log